# Java folder disappeared from program files Windows10

Tags: java, java-home

A few weeks ago I installed Java, set JAVA_HOME on my computer and the JDK in my IDE. Everything worked fine, until today. I got an error when starting my IDE, "Cannot run program" and the path I installed my Java. I checked the path and it's really not there, also "java version" and "java home" commands from the command prompt now can't find it.
I installed it again, and now after a couple of hours the bin folder disappeared!
Adding more info: I'm using java 1.8.0.261
Full error:
Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_261\bin\java.exe" (in directory "C:\Users[my_username]\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIC2021.2\compile-server"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Do you use a live system (Booting from a CD every time)? Did you perform an update of your operating system? Did you load a restore point? Did you reinstall your operating system? Do you use Antivirus Software?

Comment: Java doesn't magically disappear unless you or someone else uninstalled it (or manually deleted it). In any case, this doesn't seem to be a programming question.

Comment: @dan1st Antivirus could be a hint

Comment: Things getting uninstalled is not a programming question, as such it belongs on SuperUser or elsewhere, not on Stack Overflow. Maybe you're using a managed system and your system administrators remotely uninstalled it, maybe you're running a tool that automatically updates things, and you have a newer version in a different directory. Maybe your computer is infected with malware...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and found that during some updates it moves the java runtime to an app data folder on windows 10 under the name Sun/Java